# terraform apply not updating the ecs task when there is a variable update how to do force update?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

Hi team when ever i do run `terraform apply` it is not recreating the service task of ecs and not deploying it as well, even though i have added force deploy option as below,

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "pq-backend-task" {
  family = "pq-backend-task"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name                 = "pq-backend-container"
      image                = "${data.terraform_remote_state.infra.outputs.pq_backend_ecr_url}:latest"
      cpu                  = 2
      memory               = 4096
      essential            = true
      force_new_deployment = true
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 80
          hostPort      = 0
        }
      ]
      environment : [
        {
          "name" : "DB_PASSWORD",
          "value" : var.DB_PASSWORD
        },
        {
          "name:" : "BUILD_NO",
          "value" : var.BUILD_NO
        },
      ]
    }
  ])
}
```

In above example I have updated the environment variable of BUILD_NO, but terraform run always says as below,

`No changes. Your infrastructure still matches the configuration.`  , So how should I do force update? any workaround ?

Comment: Are there any `lifecycle` blocks defined in the rest of the resource code block?

Comment: no nothing like lifecycle i have added

Comment: Can you add the entire resource? Also, are you sure you are in the right directory?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the latest tag, use the image digest.

You can use a data block to retrieve image digest:

```
data "aws_ecr_image" "service_image" {
  repository_name = "image-name"
  image_tag       = "latest"
}
```

Then update your container definition to: `$ACCOUNT_NUMBER.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com/image-name:latest@${data.aws_ecr_image.service_image.image_digest}`.

Edit: You also have a typo in your container definition:

```
        {
          "name:" : "BUILD_NO",
          "value" : var.BUILD_NO
        },
```

There's an extra colon next to the `name` attribute.

Comment: This is great advice, but if the poster actually did update the build variable as they stated, that should be sufficient to detect a change in the container definition.

Comment: actually the issue was while i was running wihth refresh-only commad like "terraform --refresh-only apply " and this was the reason it was not doing so, once i removed it started to work 

@javierlga if i give justs the repository name then it is failing stating repository not found, can you help me with proper syntax for ECR repo as i think this would be better approach

Comment: Glad you fixed it @NaggappanRamukannan. The correct syntax for pulling an image using the digest is the following: `$ACCOUNT_NUMBER.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com/image-name:latest@sha256:...`